# Getting below error response when creating a calendar event using Graph API

Tags: c#, outlook-graph-api

Below is response received from API call.

```
{
  "code": "ErrorIrresolvableConflict",
  "message": "The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item.",
  "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bbc52dac-4523-5008-8940-e7c56c013c3a",
      "date": "2020-01-07T13:22:47"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, you can have a delay of some milliseconds between multiple posts.
You can put 100 milliseconds delay at every Post.

Refer to this post:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/error-19761-when-sending-mail-the-send-or-update/8b9d8c7d-18ac-4543-ab7e-f51d92847bd5?auth=1

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I am not doing multiple posts. I am trying to create only one event and getting this response.